# Get and delete all documents in a Firestore subcollection

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get and delete all the documents in a subcollection called "journal" but it doesn't work and did not show any toast message or errors.

It would be very helpful if someone tells me what is wrong. Thank you a lot.

This is the code I use to get and delete all the documents in a subcollection:

```
final String userid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    FirebaseFirestore. getInstance().collection("main").document(userid).collection("journal").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (final QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

 db.collection("main").document(userid).collection("journal").document(document.getId()).delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Deleted: " + document.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "error getting: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Firestore structure :

```
collection(main) ---> document(userid)---> collection(journal)---> document 1
                                                              ---> document 2
                                                              --> document 3
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and tell us if something is tosted in onFailure?

Comment: @AlexMamo screenshot added, the strange thing is that nothing is toasted onFailure or onSuccess :/

Comment: I cannot see any "journal" collection in your screenshot. Please add the correct one.

Comment: @AlexMamo Hi, sorry, just added the correct one :)

Comment: Is  your onComplete even triggered?

Comment: @AlexMamo oh right, there is no onFailure toast about the onComplete either, so probably not triggered :(

Comment: In that case, you have no internet connection on the device. Make sure to be connected.

Comment: @AlexMamo I will check it again, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
final String userid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("main").document(userid).collection("journal").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
        for (DocumentSnapshot document: queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments()) {
            db.collection("main").document(userid).collection("journal").document(document.getId()).delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Deleted: " + document.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Also, please make sure you have set your db rules to allow **delete** event